# Scala sbt unable to find commons-logging-1.0.4.jar

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to get an open source project running with scala that is built using sbt.

I downloaded sbt and set it up.  But when I try to run sbt from the command line, I get the following error.

> :: problems summary :: :::: WARNINGS      [NOT FOUND  ]
>   commons-logging#commons-logging;1.0.4!commons-logging.jar (1ms)
>
> ==== Maven2 Local: tried
>
> file:///Users/jeremy/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0.4/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
>
> ```
>   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
>
>   ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
>
>   :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
>
>   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
>
>   :: commons-logging#commons-logging;1.0.4!commons-logging.jar
>
>   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
> ```
>
> :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS download
>   failed: commons-logging#commons-logging;1.0.4!commons-logging.jar
>   Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries   (see
>   /Users/jeremy/sourceCode/public/scalaConsole/project/boot/update.log
>   for complete log) Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.10.1

Any ideas on how I could resolve this.

I have scala 2.9.1 and sbt version 0.10.1

Thanks

Comment: I have manually pulled that file from the maven repository and it appears to work now.  I am not sure why it could not get it.  Because I have pulled that file, my update.log file is no longer there with the error.

Comment: Then probably remove the file again ...

Comment: I have the same problem with sbt 0.11.0.  Here is my update.log file: https://gist.github.com/1274448

Comment: I had the same issue and got around it by manually downloading the jar and putting it in my local maven repository

Answer (score 10):

It worked for me after I removed both `~/.m2/repository/commons-logging` and `~/.ivy2/cache/commons-logging`. If sbt founds none of this two paths it will actually try and download the commons logging package.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes maven doesn't download the files correctly and you'll only find a .pom file in the repository and no commons-logging-1.0.4.jar file.  First I removed ~/.m2/repository/commons-logging.  Then I downloaded the jar manually from http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0.4/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar and finally installed the jar using the mvn install command:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=commons-logging -DartifactId=commons-logging -Dversion=1.0.4 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a proxy server? If so you may need to modify your sbt bat or sh script to pass along the proxy information to the JVM like so:

```
java -XX:MaxPermSize=96m -Xmx512m -Dhttp.proxyHost=my.proxy.server.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=1234 -jar sbt-launch-0.10.1.jar
```

Comment: I have the same problem with sbt 0.11.0.  It is not a proxy issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the root cause of the issue is.  But I use a script that automatically installs and launches sbt; so I modified the script to download commons-logging before running sbt.

The sbt launcher is here: https://gist.github.com/1274530

To run sbt, save the script somewhere in your $PATH, make sure that is executable, and run it by typing `sbt`.

Answer (score 0):

Add http://repo1.maven.org/maven to the maven.repo.remote property in your project.properties file.  This will download the file from the maven2 remote repository.

Old entry:

```
maven.repo.remote=http://www.ibiblio.org/maven
```

New entry:

```
maven.repo.remote=http://www.ibiblio.org/maven,http://repo1.maven.org/maven
```